# How to get a serialized variable from a CURL post?

Tags: php, curl

I'm making a non-associative array, I then want to serialize this and send it to another page using CURL as so:

```
   $test[]='T1';
    $test[]='T2';
    $test[]='T3';
    $test[]='T4';
    $test[]='T5';

    $str = serialize($test);
    $strenc = urlencode($str);        
    $url = '//myURL';

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strenc);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_exec( $ch );
```

But what should I use on the other page to get the serialized data. Without an associative array name index to call in the POST? I tried `$_POST['test'];` but that didn't work.

TIA

Comment: Hint: `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Try outputting your $_REQUEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to encode data (urlencode). Just replace:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strenc);
```

with

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('test' => $str));
```

to retrive test array in web script, use:

```
$test = unserialize($_POST['test']);
```